# store 2 values in one variable?

Tags: python, store

I am wondering, is there a way that i can store start and end values on my main method. I try doing this but it give me error:

```
def searchM():

    fileAddress = '/database/pro/data/'+ID+'.txt'
    with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='M']/lcn")
            start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
            end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
    return "%s, %s" % (start, end,)

values = searchM()

(start, end,) = values
```

The error message is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start' referenced before assignment

Comment: This line of code: `return "%s, %s" % (start, end,)` is being executed in cases when `start` has not been assigned. Now has `end` for that matter. Even if you fix it, `(start, end,) = values` is not going to work. You can't unpack a string into two variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what should i do instead to get these two values?

Comment: Well, just return them in a tuple: `return (start, end)`. And then unpack them like this: `(start, end) = searchM()`. Obviously you need to make sure `start` and `end` are assigned though.

Comment: use `return start, end`. Note you don't need parentheses (the comma creates a tuple in this case)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's true. However, I can imagine folk that prefer to see the `(x, y)` style because it is more visually striking. And I didn't want to suggest style changes when we are dealing with much more prosaic issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to the `start` and `end` variables.  Try initializing them first so that they exist in the even that a value is not set.

In addition, you are trying to create and return a string, which is then unpacked into two different variables.

Try the following:

```
def searchM():
    fileAddress = '/database/pro/data/%s.txt' % ID
    start = None
    end = None
    with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
        for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='M']/lcn"):
            start = int(lcn.get("start")) #if it is PFAM then look for start value
            end = int(lcn.get("end")) #if it is PFAM then also look for end value
    return start, end

(start, end) = searchM()
```

Comment: will i be able to call the start and end values on another method using that? how would i call those start and end values on another method

Comment: Using `values = searchM()`..`(start, end,) = values`.  Although assigning the returned values to a variable first is not necessary as you're currently doing.  You can simply return the result to the desired variables: `(start, end) = searchM()`

Comment: Is there a way to make start = '' and end ='' as an int not a string because when i compile later on the entire code, which i use list[start]. the complier wouldn't let me do it because it is a string

Comment: Initialize them as `start = 0` and `end = 0`

Comment: there is no conflict; you would get the same error if you change the names. It is incorrect to return 0,0 for "not found" case if they are valid indexes i.e., if lcn.get() can return 0

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - Perhaps conflict was not the right choice of words. I've updated the phrasing and modified it to initialize as `None` so that the type will be inherited when the variables are set.  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide values for `start`, `end` if they are not found:

```
for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='M']/lcn"):
    start = int(lcn.get("start"))
    end = int(lcn.get("end"))
    break
else: # not found
    start = end = None
```

Comment: It expresses the author's intent as I understand it

Comment: You may very well be correct there, but I just wanted it explicitly stated

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thank you very much. Could i ask you another question? I need to use start and end value on another method to make list. but it told me that that the value either cant be NoneType or str. How would i solve this?

Comment: @ChadD: `None` values mean that xpath returned empty list i.e., nothing is found. What you should do depends on how the list will be used in your code later.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree. Thank you for mentioning it